# Many-to-many Unique Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to come up with an efficient solution to this design problem. In essence, the application has a **Company** model. Each **Company** can be "located" in multiple locations (i.e. San Francisco, New York, London, etc.). Similarly, each location can have multiple companies associated to it. Because of this, my intuition was to have a has_many_belongs_to_many relationship between the **Company** model and a **Location** model. For example:

**Company A** has locations in **San Francisco and New York**.

**Company B** has locations in **London, San Francisco, and Munich**.

**Company C** has locations in **Miami**.

Currently, my ActiveRecord relationships are setup as following:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

I'm trying to achieve the functionality that a user can "add a location" to a company, and if that location already exists then it will be associated with that company. Otherwise, if the location does not already exist, it will be created and then associated with that company. Following the example above:

**Company D** is created. It has locations in **Miami and Houston**. Since **Miami** is already in the database, a reference is made from **Miami** to Company D. However, since **Houston** is not in the table, it is first created and then the relationship is made between **Houston** and **Company D**.

I thought a good way to do this would be to use a unique index of some sort, but that is preventing me from adding the same city twice (obviously). Essentially, is there a way that I can create a relationship between a Company and Location that "checks" if a location inputted is already present in the Location table, and if so makes the reference/association. Not sure if I am approaching this the right 'Rails' way or overcomplicating it/whether I even need a has_many_belongs_to_many relationship. Any help/guidance appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is way in which you can check if the location is already exists then create relationship between company and location or if location does not exists then first create location and then create relationship by using `find_or_create` method in rails

use this method in before_filter before the action which is creating company and location relationship
https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create